# Django: overriding predefined save() method - request is not defined

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to [override the save() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) on a Django model so that some fields are automatically filled out. This is the model:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=1500, null=True, blank=True)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user:
            self.user = request.user
        self.url = request.path
        self.ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

What I'm trying to do is to automatically set the user, URL, and IP fields when I save a record, without having to do that in the view. However, in the current format the request is not "passed" to the model, and I'm not sure how I am supposed to do that.

This is what I currently get:

> name 'request' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program logic should be handled in a view and only database or model related stuff should be used in your models (The reason is views are exactly made for this). So you could better do this in view as,

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    blog = Blog.objects.create(user_id=request.user.id, url=request.path, ip=socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
```

If you specifically want to access request in models (you should not do this anyway), just send it as a kwarg.

```
Blog.objects.save(req=request)
```

And capture it as,

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    request = kwargs.get('request', None)
    if request:
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            self.user = request.user
        self.url = request.path
```

Comment: Thanks! But my problem is that I call Blog.objects.save() from many different places in the view, and _every_ time I would repeat the same code to set IP, URL, user. Wouldn't it make sense to put it in the model? Otherwise I have a lot of repeated code...

Comment: its is not a good practice, only models and related stuff should go in models else once your application grow, it will be hard to maintain. Don't practice this.

Comment: Would it be better to set a default value in the model then? I can do that for the IP, but again I don't know how to do it for the URL and user. Any thoughts?

Comment: wrap it to a function if you think it repeating. an example would be `def populate_blogs(user_instance, request):` which you can call as `populate_blogs(request.user, request)`  to populate the content. Set default value for model fields if its absolute necessary. It doesn't make sense to default all `ip_addess` to `8.8.8.8`

Comment: OK thanks, I'll look into that. I am setting the IP address by default to 'socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())' which seems to work well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use request in the save override on the model (though I am prepared for a more knowledgeable person to correct me there). My solution would I think be to do it in the view, not the model.

```
blog_form = BlogForm(request.POST)
if blog_form.is_valid():
    blog = blog_form.save(commit=False)
    blog.user = request.user
    blog.save()
```

(Minor aside: You also seem to have spaces between `*` and `args` and `kwargs`. I honestly don't know if this matters or not, but it's very non-standard, and certainly looks odd and not Pythonic)

Comment: Thanks! I hope that there is a way though, because I save a lot of records in many places in the view, so it would be a lot of duplicated code if I can't put it in the model. Let's see. I've fixed the spaces by the way, you are right, it was copied from the PDF manual which is why it somehow ended up with extra spaces.